# Converting Pounds/Ounces to Pounds in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

is there a formula where I can convert pounds/ounces to just ounces or pounds? For instance, I have one cell that says 6 lbs 10 oz., is there a formula to change that to 106 oz? Thanks!

Comment: `6 lbs 10 oz.` is a text string and therefore you will need to parse the string to do the math.  There is not a set formula that will do it all.  It will require nested formula.

Comment: Thanks, can you explain in further detail if you don't mind?

Comment: @CLook see I have posted in answer

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above by **[Scott Craner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4851590/scott-craner)** Sir,

> *6 lbs 10 oz. is a text string and therefore you will need to parse the string to do the math. There is not a set formula that will do it all. It will require nested formula.*

Hence you could try the following formulas as per your suit

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `E1`

```
=SUM(TEXTSPLIT(A1,"oz","lbs",1)*{16;1})&" oz"
```

---

Or,

• Formula used in cell `D1`

```
=LET(x,TEXTSPLIT(A1,"oz","lbs",1),TAKE(x,1)*16+TAKE(x,-1)&" oz")
```

---

Or,

• Formula used in cell `B1`

```
=CONVERT(TEXTBEFORE(A1,"lbs")/1,"lbm","ozm")+
TEXTAFTER(TEXTBEFORE(A1," oz"),"lbs ")&" oz"
```

---

Or,

• Formula used in cell `C1`

```
=LET(x,TEXTSPLIT(A1,"oz","lbs",1)+0,
CONVERT(TAKE(x,1),"lbm","ozm")+TAKE(x,-1)&" oz")
```

---

Since not sure about your `Excel Version` posting two alternatives more.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `F1`

```
=SUM(FILTERXML("<m><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</b><b>")&"</b></m>","//b[position() mod 2 = 1]")*{16;1})&" oz"
```

---

Or,

• Formula used in cell `G1`

```
=SUM(MID(" "&A1,SEARCH({"lbs","oz"},A1)-2,2)*{16,1})&" oz"
```

---

**Note:** The last formula will work as long as the `lbs` & `oz` are 2 digits values.

---